# VBA Excel - Word Wrap

Tags: excel, vba, word-wrap

I'm creating a small piece of VBA code with a specific formula, however it has a couple of `if` statements, one of which originates a double-line string (with `vbNewLine`)
The issue is that I can't see the text.

So I wanted to word wrap it, but each time I set the `ActiveCell.WrapText = True`, nothing happens.

I checked with a message box. I set the `WrapText` to True, I return the property value with the MessageBox to confirm, and it's still False.

I've been told to use `ActiveCell.Rows.AutoFit` as well, but `AutoFit` does nothing if the text isn't wrapped.

Any idea what I might be doing wrong here?

Comment: Please: less slang and filler words, more well-formatted code samples. This question is quite difficult to read and understand, basically, like. Whassup wit dat?

Answer (score 17):

try:

```
Sub WrapandFit()

    ActiveCell.WrapText = True
    ActiveCell.EntireRow.AutoFit

End Sub
```

It worked for me. Make sure that your screenupdating is also set to true.

Comment: I do apologize, was only trying to be polite since English ain't my main language. Anyways the problem continues tho, if I place that code in a macro it works, in the function it does not.

(Also sorry, but I'm not very familiar with Stack Overflow as of yet... Think I placed the English thing comment in the wrong place.)

Comment: If the spreadsheet isnt that data intensive, you can ad a - on cell change - in your workbook. Every time a cell is changed, it can call the macro code to update the activecell height. Note though that if this spreadsheet in any way gets large it going to be very slow!

Answer (score 6):

For me, the code below worked. (only set to change header row, (change range))

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A1:R1").Select
With Selection
    .WrapText = True
End With
```

Answer (score 3):

UDFs (procedures that use the keyword Function) only return values.  They cannot change other parts of the Excel object model, like cell formatting.  Only Subroutines (procedures that use the keyword Sub) can do that.

You need to have your cells formatted properly before you enter your UDF.  Or you could use a worksheet change event sub to format them after the fact.

Answer (score 1):

Turn off/On word wrap for whole sheet row can be done by VB code shown below:
If the first row is set true, excel inherits that property for whole sheet, unless you specifically turned it off using another code.

```
MyWorkSheet.Rows.WrapText = True
```

To turn off wrapping property of a specific row:

```
MyWorkSheet.Rows(8).WrapText = False
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you are trying to wrap text in merged cells. If yes, you cannot simply call:

```
MyWorkSheet.Rows.WrapText = True
```

Instead, you have to simulate the wrapping operations. I found the code from http://blog.contextures.com/archives/2012/06/07/autofit-merged-cell-row-height/ helped me last year.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim MergeWidth As Single
Dim cM As Range
Dim AutoFitRng As Range
Dim CWidth As Double
Dim NewRowHt As Double
Dim str01 As String
str01 = "OrderNote"

  If Not Intersect(Target, Range(str01)) Is Nothing Then
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    On Error Resume Next
    Set AutoFitRng = Range(Range(str01).MergeArea.Address)

    With AutoFitRng
      .MergeCells = False
      CWidth = .Cells(1).ColumnWidth
      MergeWidth = 0
      For Each cM In AutoFitRng
          cM.WrapText = True
          MergeWidth = cM.ColumnWidth + MergeWidth
      Next
      'small adjustment to temporary width
      MergeWidth = MergeWidth + AutoFitRng.Cells.Count * 0.66
      .Cells(1).ColumnWidth = MergeWidth
      .EntireRow.AutoFit
      NewRowHt = .RowHeight
      .Cells(1).ColumnWidth = CWidth
      .MergeCells = True
      .RowHeight = NewRowHt
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I had this issue with row height and didn't realize it was due to merged cells. This this solved my problem!

Answer (score 0):

This may not be exactly what the OP had in mind but I figured I'd share my VBA [**Word Wrap**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_wrap_and_word_wrap) function since I couldn't find anything on the web to do what I wanted.

This function insert [**<kbd>CR</kbd>**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return)+[<kbd>LF</kbd>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline)'s into the string in order to wrap it, so the word wrap is maintained if the text is copied to another application, text-based or otherwise.

```
Function wrapText(strIn As String, Optional maxLen As Long = 110) As String
    Dim p As Long: wrapText = strIn
    Do
        p = InStrRev(wrapText, " ", p + maxLen) - 1
        wrapText = Left(wrapText,p) & vbCrLf & Right(wrapText, Len(wrapText)-p-1)
        Debug.Print Mid(Replace(wrapText, vbCrLf, "||"), p - 20)
        'Stop
    Loop While p + maxLen < Len(wrapText)
End Function
```

It defaults to maximum width of 115 characters but can optionally be changed to anything. It only breaks on spaces  (the last one that appears on/before position #115), and it only inserts [CR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return) + [LF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline)'s (with the constant [`vbCrLf`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/miscellaneous-constants)), but they can be adapted as required.

As an example of application, I was building complex SQL queries in Excel and wanted to copy the SQL over to the server app neat & tidy, instead of one giant line.